# How does git diff -M work?

Tags: git, diff

I am currently trying to figure out how `git diff -M<limit>` works.

What I found out is, that `git diff` checks how similar two files (say `fileA` in revision 1, `fileC` in revision 2) are by calculating a similarity score. If the similarity score is >= `limit`,  `fileA` has been renamed to `fileC` which has possibly been modified (if score is < 100%).

Then I asked myself, what if there are more files with the same sha1-hash within the directory? How does `git` know which one is the renamed (and changed) version?

To find this out, I tried the following:

First, I created two files with 7 lines ("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g")

```
vi fileA
vi fileB
```

Then I added them to the repository and committed:

```
git add fileA fileB
git commit -m "Added fileA and fileB"

    [master ffc8964] Added fileA and fileB
     2 files changed, 6 insertions(+)
     create mode 100644 tests/fileA
     create mode 100644 tests/fileB
```

Next, I renamed `fileA` to `fileC` using `git mv` and deleted the first line in `fileB` and `fileC`. After that I commited the changes

```
git mv fileA fileC
vi fileB
vi fileC
git commit -a -m "Renamed and changed files"

    [master 57ff82a] Renamed and changed filed
     2 files changed, 2 deletions(-)
     rename tests/{fileA => fileC} (85%)
```

`fileB` and `fileC` now look like this:

```
b
c
d
e
f
g
```

What I expected now is that the checksums of `fileB` and `fileC` are equal:

```
git hash-object fileB fileC
    9fbb6235d2d7eb798268d4537acebea297321241
    9fbb6235d2d7eb798268d4537acebea297321241
```

Indeed they are :-)

So how should `git diff` now know what the renamed file is? Since fileC has been changed, a new blob has been generated by `commit` and the checksum of `fileC` and `fileA` are different as well (obviously).

I tried it:

```
git diff -M80% HEAD master~1
```

The output however confused me :-(

```
diff --git a/tests/fileC b/tests/fileA
similarity index 85%
rename from tests/fileC
rename to tests/fileA
index 9fbb623..f9d9a01 100644
--- a/tests/fileC
+++ b/tests/fileA
@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@
+a
 b
 c
 d
diff --git a/tests/fileB b/tests/fileB
index 9fbb623..f9d9a01 100644
--- a/tests/fileB
+++ b/tests/fileB
@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@
+a
 b
 c
 d
```

Apparently `git diff` DID find out that `fileA` has been renamed to `fileC`.

But how? Did git save some kind of connection between `fileA` and `fileC`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No such connection was saved. Renames can be detected when one file is deleted, and another is added. Git saw that `fileC` was newly added, and went through all deleted files to see if it might have been a rename. Here, the only deleted file was `fileA`, so it was a rather quick check.

Note: it only has to go through the deleted files, because otherwise you wouldn't have a rename, you'd have a copy. Copies can be detected too, and it works roughly the same way, but they're covered by a separate option (`-C`).

Comment: This is how I imagine `commit` to detect renames. But how does `git diff` know? Does it consult the histories of both commits?

Comment: @Paddre A commit doesn't store the changes, it stores the new tree. Commands such as `git diff` calculate the changes on demand. So `git diff` has immediate access to the directories and files in both commits, without having to go through the histories.

Comment: Thx (makes perfect sense...don't know what was wrong in my mind yestderday night :-P ). So `git diff` checks whether there is an added file which is sufficiently similar to a deleted file, right?
So I tried the following: `git mv fileC fileD`, `cp fileD fileE`, delete first lines of `fileD` and `fileE`, `git add fileE`. Now there has been a renaming (that is a deletion and an addition) and an addition and both the renamed and the added file have the same checksum. How does `git diff` still find out that `fileD` has been the renamed version of `fileC`?

Comment: @Paddre It doesn't, it guesses. You'll see the exact same result if you do `git mv fileC fileE`, and then `cp fileE fileD`: git will still detect a rename from `fileC` to `fileD`.

Comment: Thanks. That helped me a lot (even though the answer is somewhat "sobering" :-D ). I think this works because it doesn't matter which file has been the renamed one. The base file doesn't exist any more in the newer revision) anyway and so di `fileD` and `fileE` regarding the older revision. So it doesn't matter whether `fileD` or `fileE` is the renamed version of `fileC`